# Where can I find the configurations corresponding to the current largest max-cut values on $G$-set graphs?

Tags: ising-model, data, graph-theory

I am looking for the configurations that are behind the max-cut value in many articles about solving the Ising problem/max-cut problem on graphs, but I can't seem to find any articles with this data included. I am interested in the $G$-set graphs only.